# Group lines by prefix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a file full of keys and values which I use for i18n. The file looks like this:

```
foo.foo=Some string
foo.bar=Some string
bar.foo=Some string
bar.bar=Some string
baz.foo=Some string
baz.bar=Some string
```

Using some unix tool like awk or sed, how can I filter the file so that lines beginning with the same prefix (up to the first dot) are grouped together, and groups are separated by a blank line?

The output should look like

```
foo.foo=Some string
foo.bar=Some string

bar.foo=Some string
bar.bar=Some string

baz.foo=Some string
baz.bar=Some string
```

Comment: Are the lines already grouped together in the input?

Comment: @TomFenech They would be if I first pipe the file through `sort`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F. '$1!=a && NR>1 {print ""} 1; {a=$1}' file
foo.foo=Some string
foo.bar=Some string

bar.foo=Some string
bar.bar=Some string

baz.foo=Some string
baz.bar=Some string
```

Answer (score 2):

While this does not exactly meet your specifications (`awk`, `sed`, separation by `.`), it would work for your example:

You can use `uniq` to group. For your example the respective command would be

```
uniq --group -w 3 file
```

`-w/--check-chars=n` is crucial for determining equality only on a prefix of n characters. Unfortunately, this does not allow for variable lengths until the `.` but for uniform prefix lengths, I find it more understandable than the awk solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F. 'a!=$1{print '\n';a=$1}1' File
```

Set `.` as field seperator. copy `first field` to variable `a`. Whenever a line contains a new value for `first field` (i.e `a!=$1`), print a `newline`.

**Output:**

```
AMD$ awk -F. 'a!=$1{print '\n';a=$1}1' File

foo.foo=Some string
foo.bar=Some string

bar.foo=Some string
bar.bar=Some string

baz.foo=Some string
baz.bar=Some string
```

Comment: That would print an undesirable leading blank line and you cannot use single quotes within a single-quote-delimited script so I don't even know how that script is executing without a syntax error.